# textarea placeholder message

Tags: javascript, forms

Just doing a text area, and for inputs we can use placeholder text:

```
name="inputname" value="Enter Text Here" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Text Here') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Text Here'; }"
```

But in **textarea** it doesnt work, until you click in the field and back out again.

Any fix for this please ?

**TO ADD**

We are pulling saved entry from form, and spewing it out between the tag elements like:

```
......><?=str_replace("<br />", "", $somestuff);?></textarea>
```

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/acxEr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default text for textarea goes in between the tags, not in the value attribute, like this:

```
<textarea name="inputname" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Text Here') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Text Here'; }">Enter Text Here</textarea>
```

Comment: If the value of the textarea is replaced dynamically, with values from db, then this will create issues, plus I am sure your code above is incorrect.

Comment: @drachenstern, some (if not all, and I suspect this is the case) browsers ignore a `value` attribute on `<textarea>` elements. The correct way to provide a default value on a `<textarea>` element in HTML is between its opening and closing tags.

Comment: @eyelidlessness notice I redacted my comment, my eyes were faster than my brain

Comment: But what if we have value between tags set like so: <?=str_replace("<br />", "", $somestuff);?>

Comment: Then you would check the length of the input to be 0 and if so replace with the text you provided ... like `<?=str_replace("<br />", "", ($somestuff.length == 0)?"Enter Text Here":$somestuff) ?>`

Comment: I may have written it incorrectly. All I'm saying is set the value of $somestuff to "Enter Text Here" if $somestuff is of length 0 ... You'll have to work with the concept accordingly I fear

Comment: @422 if that worked, go ahead and take Dustin's answer ;) ... grats

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `value`, but now the text is within the `textarea` element.

```
<textarea 
name="inputname" value="Enter Text Here" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Text Here') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Text Here'; }" >Enter Text Here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jsfiddle.net/KG5UE/4/

Your code works just fine for me in Chrome. Here's a jsfiddle to prove it.

Oh, for textarea? Sorry, my fingers are faster than my eyes....

Go for what Dustin said, he's right .... Updated jsfiddle to include both cases

Comment: you are using input not textarea drach

Comment: @422 And to you sir. How's the weather? I hear ya'll have some flooding somewhere down there, but I also hear the country's nearly as big as ours ;) ... I answered further on Dustin's post

Comment: Mate we were flooded in the week, and housebound for a few days. But we escaped as one of the lucky ones , thank god

Comment: Glad to hear that for you guys. Always good to hear that people made it out the other side to see the sun another day and stand on dry ground.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following file on IE7 and it worked.

```
<html>

<body>

<textarea name="inputname" value="Enter Text Here" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Text Here') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Text Here'; }" ></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```